# ASP.NET MVC 3 with Razor DropDownListFor change not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I've seen a lot of questions on here regarding DropDownList and DropDownListFor events not firing but no answers that solve my problem. I don't think I've overlooked anything so I'll post my own question...

I have the following code in my View:

```
@model MyWebApp.ViewModels.ProductAdminViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage Products";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('select#CurrentCategoryId').change(function () {
            alert('We got here!');
        })
    });
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "indexGrid" }))
{ 
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select Category</legend><span>Category: </span>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CurrentCategoryId, Model.CategorySelectList, new { @id = "CurrentCategoryId" })
    </fieldset>
}
<div id="indexGrid">
    @Html.Partial("_indexGrid", Model)
</div>
```

The drop-down is populated correctly from the SelectList in my ViewModel and the only other thing to note is that the CurrentCategoryId in the VM is a public int property.

What have I overlooked in tying the drop-down to the script?

EDIT: I have the following in my _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/lightbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/EditorTypes.js"></script>
```

Thanks to @Hawkke. This is my working code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CategoryChanged(newCategoryId) {
        alert('The category has been changed!');
    };
</script>
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CurrentCategoryId, Model.CategorySelectList, new { @onchange = "CategoryChanged(" + @Model.CurrentCategoryId + ")" })
```

Comment: do you have jQuery referenced anywhere?

Comment: Can you paste the html output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'select#CurrentCategoryId'` is expecting a control named 'CurrentCategoryId', but the  name of your dropdown list is the VM's id.

**Edit**

What I would do is change your javascript from a jQuery function to a regular function.

```
<script>
    function ChangeMe(currentCategoryId) {
        // do stuff here
    }
</scrip>
```

Then change your html helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CurrentCategoryId, Model.CategorySelectList, 
    new { onchange = "ChangeMe(@Model.CurrentCategoryId)" })
```

I'm not 100% on the razor syntax but I think you get the idea.

Comment: Does ", new { @id = "CurrentCategoryId" }" not provide that link?

Comment: Edit: I think you're right, I didn't see that you weren't specifying @id = Model.CurrentCategoryId, but instead the actual string "CurrentCategoryId." See my edit for how I'd do it.

Comment: Thanks hawkke, this had me on the right path. I've posted the finished code below the question for those that are interested.